# Deleted the python@3.9 file but still exists in the terminal

Tags: python, pip

Why does this line keep occurring when I trying to know the version of pip? How can I eliminate it? I deleted the python@3.9 file but still exists in the terminal.

```
$ pip --version                                                                                                                                                                            
zsh: /opt/homebrew/bin/pip: bad interpreter: /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/bin/python3.9: no such file or directory
pip 22.2.2 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip (python 3.10)
```

```
ls -l /usr/local/bin/python*                                                                                                                                                             ok | 10:12:57
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root        wheel  70  9 26 09:39 /usr/local/bin/python3 -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/python3
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root        wheel  77  9 26 09:39 /usr/local/bin/python3-config -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/python3-config
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root        wheel  78  9 26 09:39 /usr/local/bin/python3-intel64 -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/python3-intel64
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root        wheel  73  9 26 09:39 /usr/local/bin/python3.10 -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/python3.10
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root        wheel  80  9 26 09:39 /usr/local/bin/python3.10-config -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/python3.10-config
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root        wheel  81  9 26 09:39 /usr/local/bin/python3.10-intel64 -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/python3.10-intel64
lrwxr-xr-x  1 juchanpark  admin  43  7 18 19:12 /usr/local/bin/python3.9 -> ../Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.13_1/bin/python3.9
lrwxr-xr-x  1 juchanpark  admin  50  7 18 19:12 /usr/local/bin/python3.9-config -> ../Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.13_1/bin/python3.9-config
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+bad+interpreter